# Does rails not support html list attribute on input tag?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

What I'm trying to achieve is something like this in rails

https://jsfiddle.net/uxc45hcs/

But rails doesn't seems to support HTML attribute "list"

```
.col-md-2.execute_at_input = f.input :execute_at, label: "Execute Attt", placeholder: " In Minutes ", list: 'listid'
```

The above code outputs the following:

```
<input class="string optional form-control" placeholder=" In Minutes " type="text" value="" name="execute_at" data-validate="true">
```

Where as it should be:

```
<input class="string optional form-control" placeholder=" In Minutes " type="text" value="" name="execute_at" data-validate="true" list="listid">
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work: (tested in rails 5)

`<%= f.text_field :name, :class => 'form-control col-md-2', :placeholder => 'In Minutes', :list => "listid" %>`

Answer (score 1):

This works with [`text_field`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/text_field)

```
.col-md-2.execute_at_input= f.text_field :execute_at, label: "Execute Attt", placeholder: " In Minutes ", list: 'listid'
```

This resulted in following output

```
<div class="col-md-2 execute_at_input">
  <input id="execute_at" label="Execute Attt" list="listid" name="execute_at" placeholder=" In Minutes " size="30" type="text" maxlength="255">
</div>
```

If you are using [Formtastic](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic) check for the syntax